# How to create HTML comment box without database

Tags: html

I need a simple comment box, made without a database (so HTMLcommentbox.com is not for me).  You can only use it one time per page.  We only have one page but may have more then one person who needs their own comments.  The URL of our TLC is http://www.copd-supporttlc.byethost7.com/.  I am using Elvis as a placeholder and practice until I have everything set up.

There will be more names below Elvis and I would like to have a comment box for each name and more folks would comment one that name and I would like to have it collapse when not in use.  It would open when you clicked on the name.

Comment: Where do you want to store the data (comments) if not in a database?

Comment: you could implement disqus https://disqus.com/admin/create/

Comment: yeah, if you don't want to have your own database, you will have to use a 3rd party commenting system to store and host your comments section. http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/3rdparty-comment-discuss-systems-reviewed/

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create some type of comment system without storing data.  And one way or another, storing data is considered a database.  Whether you use something like SQL lite for local storage, or a large server database like MySQL.  At some point a database will be involved.

So what you are attempting is impossible.

Comment: Whilst this is absolutely correct, there are ways of hosting data without the necessity or having your OWN database, which from the context of the post I assume is the issue. Using a third party system such as those mentioned in the comments against the question would allow comments to be stored without the (presumably inexperienced) question poster having to delve into database storage. This is by no means a criticism of your answer, only an observation as a long time ago I was asking the same question! The hosting I had at the time did not include any kind of database facility...

Comment: @Lyall Yes you are absolutely correct.  Thank you for your politeness!

Comment: Manners cost nothing :)

Comment: If it is impossible or not, would like some idea how to make the comment box, even with simple database, php @Hurricane Developement